# Backbone LayoutManager Rendering Questions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using bbb (Backbone Boilerplate) which includes Backbone.LayoutManager. I have the [following Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3uaLk/1/) When you call your layout.render() method does it render all of the views inside the layout? Because when I render the layout and when I fetch my collection, it is calling the beforeRender and serialize method on each instance. So each method is being called twice. Once on layout render and once when fetching my collection. You can test with the fiddle listed. If thats the case, then why cant I overide my individual views render method, which is also listed above. I was under the impression this was possible.

How can I prevent my views inside my layout from being rendered when calling layout.render()? It is quite inefficient calling each method on an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the paginator code but it looks like you are missing you're callback function to catch the return from the twitter api. This seems to cause the 'reset' in the collection init to fire which causes a second render() to be called.

I think you need to add the server_api stuff to your paginator code to defined the callback.

```
server_api: {
   '$callback': 'callback'
}
```

This should then populate the collection.

Although you'll need to check the paginator docs for more info.